# PHP/SQL compare two table ID and view the name

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

i was making an script for our online game site,
i want to compare my result from a table to another tabl and view the id name.

[image]

from this i've successfully show the last CharacterIdx

now my problem is this part, comparing two tables

[image]

Problm solved! thanks alot!

Comment: You forgot the `$` before `saint_owner`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$DB_GAM.'.dbo.cabal_character_table WHERE CharacterIdx = '.$saint_owner;
echo "SQL= ", $sql;
$query = mssql_query($sql);
```

this will output your SQL command, so you can check if the SQL you output and send to the database is correct and as you expect it to be.

However, I think the error is in the fact that you are using mssql_ and mysql_ next to eachother:

make it into this:

```
$query = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$DB_GAM.'.dbo.cabal_character_table WHERE CharacterIdx = '.$saint_owner);
```

to start.

Comment: thank you for the answers but i got this output:
Resource id #5

Comment: No, then you are echo'ing the $query variable most probably. Copy the whole first piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You mistakenly types `mysql` instead of `mssql`, and left out the dollar sign before a variable:

```
$query = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM '.DB_GAM.'.dbo.cabal_character_table WHERE CharacterIdx = '.$saint_owner);
          ^                                                                                     ^
```